# How to let outlook not to insert MARKETING to emails from a sender

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I subscribed a weekly email list from BBC, when the email comes, the subject starts with "[MARKETING]", I believe it is inserted by the Outlook.

How can I prevent Outlook from doing this? I am using Outlook application, not online version.

Comment: I doubt that's your outlook adding that, more likely a mail server function.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things:

I don't think it's outlook doing it. Could be exchange if you have server side rules setup for adding a tag to suspected spam.

If you have a corporate mail server, check with your email administrator to see if they have a rule scheduled for detecting and tagging marketing. If so they might be able to setup an exception to stop the tagging.

Alternatively, Depending upon your spam management rules, you could try adding the sender to your permitted senders list. I don't expect this alternative to solve your issue however because it doesn't seem like a typical exchange or outlook behavior.